# Read from text and write to csv Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write the data I read from the .text to the csv file. Maybe like a simple problem for yours but I don't handle it

- The csv file will have two headers.
- What I read from text will be written in the first heade, and a static data (e.g. city name) will be entered automatically in the second header.

Sample can be reproduced, the text inside the .text file is as follows:

```
John Smith,Accounting,November
Erica Meyers,IT,March
```

The csv file is as below;

```
------------------------------------------
|information                    | city   |
------------------------------------------
|John Smith,Accounting,November | London | 
------------------------------------------
|Erica Meyers,IT,March          | Granada|
------------------------------------------
```

I tried to use `writer.Writeheader` but I had to use `Dictwriter`. It didn't solve my problem.

I create a object like follows:

```
header = ["information", "city"]
```

This code works but doesn't do what I want

```
with open('employee.txt', mode='r') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    line_count = 0
    with open('aa.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        for row in csv_reader:
           if line_count == 0:
               for column in row:
                   out_file.write('%s;' % column)
               out_file.write('\n')
               line_count += 1
           else:
               for column in row:
                   out_file.write('%s;' %column)
               out_file.write('\n')
               line_count += 1
        print(line_count)
```

Comment: What you have shown as "text" file actually is in CSV format and what you have shown as "csv" file isn't.

Comment: Well my output should be like that, like labeling

Comment: Your task would be easier if you changed the heading from "Information, City" to "Name, Department, Month, City". CSV files like to have its columns separated by commas.

Comment: You are right, csv wants data with commas, but I want to write what I read from the text as 2 different headers in two different columns, how can I do it, thank you for your valuable comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `pandas` module to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('employees.txt', 'r') as inFile:

    # Read the text file in as a list of lines using .readlines()
    employees = inFile.readlines()
    
    # Strip newline characters ('\n') from each line
    employees = [x.strip('\n') for x in employees]

    # Add city to each line
    employees = [[x, 'city'] for x in employees]


header = ["information", "city"]

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns=header)

# Write the dataframe to a csv
df.to_csv('aa.csv', header=True)
```